# Lambda Search VS Linear Search

Tags: c#, list, lambda, computer-science, linear-search

When I was debugging a lambda-based search, I noticed that it simply went through the list linearly, so it made we wonder if there was any advantage to doing a lambda search on a list in C# versus coding your own type-checking linear search on the same list.

Comment: What is lambda search?

Comment: Please add the code you're talking about. Lambdas don't affect the complexity of the search method you're using.

Comment: I don't have code. This is more of a conceptual question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lambda  method performs a linear search; therefore, the method is an O(n) operation, where n is Count.

For more detailed on Lambda read these link
[Lambda Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0b5b5bc(v=vs.110).aspx)